# angularstrap popover use ng-click in popover content when read from template file

Tags: angularjs, popover

I am displaying a set of items in an ng-repeat loop

One of the elements in each item is a button which uses a bs-popover directive to display a popup with actions that can be performed on that item via ng-click.

The popover's contents are stored in a template file and bound using data-template-url.

What I have not figured out is how to get the popover content to be rendered
Currently when I run it, the content still has the ng-click directives on it rather than being linked to the actual controller methods to be called.

Comment: Add some codes please. What have you tried right now?

Comment: it turns out if I remove the data-trigger=focus" it appears to work now.  But that leaves the popup open.  Now my issue is how to get the popup to close after someone clicks one of the actions.

(http://plnkr.co/edit/QTfgYRf8yxBG8Gn4JP6i?p=preview)